# If $G'\leq Z(G)$ implies $G'=Z(G)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If we know that $G'$ is a subgroup of a $Z(G)$, can we conclude that $G'=Z(G)$ ?

What I can see is that $G/Z(G)$ is abelain and it can not be cyclic but no further ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No not true, take $G$ non-trivial abelian, then $G'=1$ and $Z(G)=G$. For an non-abelian example, take $G=A \times Q$, where $A$ is non-trivial abelian and $Q$ is the quaternion group of order $8$. Note $Z(Q)=Q'$.

Comment: Is there any nonabelain example ?

Comment: @user130550 - You are welcome!

Comment: To be able to accept your answer,  I have to wait $5$ minutes and I 
want to sleep :)

Comment: @NickyHekster: what is your favorite team :)

Comment: @mesel my favorite team is The Netherlands!